# Convert Infix expression to list

Tags: python, infix-notation

I want to convert infix expression to list such that double digits or character are considered a single operand i.e `28*35/(21-13)` should result in `['28', '*', '35', '/', '(', '21', '-', '13', ')']`

This is the code I've written and it works fine but I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do it like with list comprehension or something

```
expression = "28*35/(21-13)"
expression.replace(' ', '') # replace spaces if any
expressionList = []
operand = ""
for char in expression:
    if char in "+-*/()":
        if operand != '':
            expressionList.append(operand)
            operand = ''
        expressionList.append(char)
    else:
        operand += char
```

Comment: Doesn't work fine , it gives `*` and not `\*`

Comment: @azro why should it give \\* ? why the extra backslash?

Comment: That's the example mentionned in  your description

Comment: @azro Oh, I have fixed it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You canno't use a `list-comprehension` as need to know previous element to split the content. The easier solution I see, is to use a `regex`

Here `(\d+|[-+()/*])` means

- `\d+` any suite of digits, or (the pipe is OR `|`)
- any char in `-+()/*`

```
import re

expression = "28*35/(21-13)"
values = re.findall(r"(\d+|[-+()/*])", expression) 
print(values) # ['28', '*', '35', '/', '(', '21', '-', '13', ')']
```

---

Add letters : `"([A-Z]+|\d+|[-+()/*])"`

Comment: what if I want to do the same with alphabets and digits combined? i.e AB+21 to result in ['AB', '+', '21']

Comment: @HuzaifaImran Do `"([A-Z]+|\d+|[-+()/*])"`

Comment: I think a slightly simpler solution is to use `split` instead of `findall`. It gives you the option for numbers and letters built-in: `re.split(r"([-+()/*])", expression)` (might need to deal with empty strings from leading/trailing operators)